# Error trying to build C# code with System.Management

Tags: c#, select, bluetooth

I'm trying to build a relatively simple console program in Visual Studio Code.  Using the 32feet.net package.
the code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Management;

const string Win32_SerialPort ="Win32_SerialPort";
SelectQuery q =new SelectQuery(Win32_SerialPort);
ManagementObjectSearcher s =new ManagementObjectSearcher(q);
foreach(object cur in s.Get()) 
{
ManagementObject mo = (ManagementObject)cur;
object id = mo.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID");
object pnpId = mo.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID");
console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0} ", id);
console.WriteLine("PNPDeviceID: {0} ", pnpId);
console.WriteLine("");
}
```

and I get the error
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SelectQuery'
does not exist in the namespace
'System.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

But when I search on SelectQuery it shows up as within the namespace System.Management
and if I type in the code window  System.Management. Visual Studio Code recognizes SystemQuery as one of the types.  What am I missing???

I expected the code to build.  But got the error mentioned above.

Comment: Did you add a package reference to `System.Management`?

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know I had to add that as a package reference.  That fixed my problem.  It raises another question but that can wait.

Comment: You should post an answer or close your question. I'd close it as "due to a typo or other minor reason"